# Array inside array or nested array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have an array like below: all the values I am getting one array only, but I don't want this way. This is the best way to do so, in php or jQuery both languages are ok for me

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [val] => facebook
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [val] => snapchat
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [val] => instagram
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [expenses] => 986532
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [expenses] => 45456
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [expenses] => 56230
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [social_id] => 15
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [social_id] => 16
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [social_id] => 17
        )

)
```

and I want to output like this..

```
$result = array(
                array(
                    "val" => "Facebook",
                    "expenses" => "84512",
                    "social_id" => 1
                ),
                array(
                    "val" => "Instagram",
                    "expenses" => "123",
                    "social_id" => 2
                )
        );
```

but this should be dynamic, the length of the above array can be varies

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the arrays to one and use array_column to get all vals or expenses in a separate array.
Then foreach one array and build the new array with the key.

```
//$a = your array 

// Grab each column separate
$val = array_column($a, "val"); 
$expenses= array_column($a, "expenses");
$social_id = array_column($a, "social_id");

Foreach($val as $key => $v){
    $arr[] = [$v, $expenses[$key], $social_id[$key]];
}

Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/nVtDf

Edit updated with the 'latest' version of the array. My code works just fine with this array to without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

to get that array style you can do it by hand for each array

```
function test(array ...$arr)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($arr as $key => $pair) {
        foreach ($pair as $item => $value) {
            $result[$item] = $value;
        }
    }


    return $result;
}


$arr1 = test( ['facebook' => 1], ['expenses' => 100]);
print_r($arr1);

/* Array (
         [facebook] => 1,
         [expenses] => 100
   )
 */

$arr2 = test( $arr1, ['more info' => 'info'] );
print_r($arr2);

/* Array (
         [facebook] => 1,
         [expenses] => 100,
         [more info] => info
   )
 */
```

you can pass it any number of

```
['Key' => 'Pair']
array('Key' => 'Pair')
```

or even a previous made array and it will add them up into 1 big array and return it